# Error: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR- in minio in node.js

Tags: reactjs, node.js, minio-client

I want to intract with minio client.
In my react-app:

```
import * as minio from 'minio'

const MinioClient = () => {

  const minioClient = new minio.Client({
    endPoint: 'localhost',
    port: 9001,
    accessKey: 'minio99',
    secretKey: 'minio123',
  })


    minioClient.makeBucket('mynewbucket','us-east-1', function (err) {
      if (err) 
          return console.log(err)
      console.log('Bucket created successfully in "buckets".')
    })

  return <>
    HI!!
  </>
}

export default MinioClient;
```

The error that I get:

```
PUT https://localhost:9001/mynewbucket net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I tried to change the `endPoint` to `'127.0.0.1'` Its not help.
I'm also tried to create a new `accessKey`, its not work.

Comment: When I add this:` useSSL:false` -the error is: `Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:9001/europetrip' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.` What can i do??

Comment: As the error suggests, either trust the self signed cert and continue using https/9001 or work around the CORs issue using http/3000. See https://github.com/minio/minio-go/issues/1000 (read all comments, the last one is a better solution)